# Retrieve facebook post URL with post_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get URL of users who share from my links, I have got the `post_id` but when I try to get full post URL, facebook asking for my access token, can I have the access token after users share?

This is my Code **[UPDATED]**:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : 'MYAPPID',
        xfbml   : true,
        status  : true,
        cookie  : true,
        version : 'v2.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<script>
function shareonfacebook(){
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Example',
            link: 'https://www.example.com',
            picture: 'Example.jpg',
            caption: 'Example',
            description: 'Example',
        },
            function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('Thanks!');
                    console.log( response );
                } else {
                    alert('Oops!');
                }
            }
        );

    };
</script>
```

Comment: Since you have a fairly small amount of code, it would be helpful to post it here. Users won't click that link.

Comment: also, be much more specific. for example, what is the error message exactly? and what for do you want to know the URL of the user? do you mean the profile url? why do you need it?

Comment: I want to make a testimonial page by someone share their testimonial on facebook, so I want to know the URL to the facebook post,

Comment: If you have the post id, then you can simply link to `https://www.facebook.com/post_id`, it will automatically redirect the user to the correct location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post ID will only be there if you authorize a user with the `publish_actions` permission:

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and
>   has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the
>   published Open Graph story.

Side Note: If you need help with the Login part, here's an article about that: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I've done the little modification so I can get the post URL, but the problem now is how to set default share post into public, because the default fb.ui share is friends

Comment: you can´t do that, the setting is completely up to the user.

Comment: is there any way that not using `fb.ui`, ie `fb.api`? or it just simply impossible to do that?

Comment: it is impossible to set it. only shady apps try to change that settings, it is completely up to the user and that´s how it´s supposed to be ;) - you can only choose a LESS open privacy setting with the feed endpoint. not sure what the relation to your question is though, this thread is not about the privacy setting.

Comment: okay, can fb.ui share into facebook page? I have drive along stackoverflow but the tutorial seems outdated

Comment: FYI: _“The feed dialog is deprecated”_ – that does not seem to be the case any more, they have added it to the docs again here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3

Comment: oh, that´s interesting, thanx for the info

Comment: yes, that's true. I'm deciding to using facebook SDK instead `fb.ui` right now

Comment: fb.ui is part of the facebook sdk ;) (to be specific, the facebook javascript sdk)